# php digital clock for london zoon

Tags: php

How to create digital clock using PHP (london time zone)

[sample clock](http://localtimes.info/Europe/United%20Kingdom/London/widget/)

Am looking this sort of one clock,

ther is a possible with ajax and php to we display similar of clock and date..

Thing is .it require too much of ajax,java script functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this?
http://www.ftls.org/en/examples/php/clock_digits.php3#s4.

Comment: Thanks , i downloaded this...but its basically image support one..i dont like

Comment: am looking something like this one

http://www.techiegyan.com/?p=296


but in php

Comment: may I ask why not using the one with jquery? if you need to refresh it the best way wouldn't be only php, it would be with "ajax"

Comment: at present i used the above one...but looking php also...
can u tell me what is the utc_offset for london

Comment: // plugin defaults
  $.fn.jclock.defaults = {
    timeNotation: '24h',
    am_pm: false,
    utc: false,
    fontFamily: '',
    fontSize: '',
    foreground: '',
    background: '',
    utc_offset: 0
  };

I tried  utc_offset: -1 but am not find any changes....
How should i configure for london city...

Comment: what difference are you watching? one hour?

Comment: Only my current system time is howing... i want to show the london time...even i tried somthing like  "utc_offset":"-18000",

Comment: sorry for the delay, why don't you try this code is really simple and will do the work ;) http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-143979.html

look for kor answer the time for london is ['London',0,60]

Answer (score 0):

Look how to work with timezones:
[php timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php)